# How to reset phpMyAdmin password? 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, lamp, phpmyadmin

I am using LAMP in Ubuntu 12.04. How to reset the phpMyAdmin password?

```
hypertext@hypertext-desktop:~$ sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &
[2] 7196
hypertext@hypertext-desktop:~$ sudo: /var/lib/sudo writable by non-owner (040777), should be mode 0700                                                         UPDATE user SET Password=admin WHERE User='root';
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

[2]+  Stopped                 sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables
hypertext@hypertext-desktop:~$ sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &
[3] 7252
hypertext@hypertext-desktop:~$ sudo: /var/lib/sudo writable by non-owner (040777), should be mode 0700
mysql -u root mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

[3]+  Stopped                 sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables
hypertext@hypertext-desktop:~$ sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &
[4] 7259
hypertext@hypertext-desktop:~$ sudo: /var/lib/sudo writable by non-owner (040777), should be mode 0700
UPDATE user SET Password='admin' WHERE User='root';FLUSH PRIVILEGES; exit;
UPDATE: command not found

[4]+  Stopped                 sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables

[4]+  Stopped                 sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables
FLUSH: command not found
exit
There are stopped jobs.
hypertext@hypertext-desktop:~$ sudo pkill mysqld
sudo: /var/lib/sudo writable by non-owner (040777), should be mode 0700
[sudo] password for hypertext: 
hypertext@hypertext-desktop:~$ sudo service mysql start
sudo: /var/lib/sudo writable by non-owner (040777), should be mode 0700
[sudo] password for hypertext: 
mysql: unrecognized service
hypertext@hypertext-desktop:~$ ^C
hypertext@hypertext-desktop:~$
```

Comment: You should try to get your MySQL service running properly, before you deal with stuff, that depends on it like PhpMyAdmin.

Comment: That is running smoothly

Comment: What are all these warnings and error messages in the above listing then? Why do you need to start the MySQL daemon multiple times over? Why is the service `mysql` unrecognised?

Comment: i have started it multiple time to reset root ppassword.. I have configureit a year later and forget it. 
Now I want:
(1)to reset/Retrive password?
OR
(2)Uninstall the package and re install it(While uninstalling also need password that i don't know)